# This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-extensions

My syslog is getting spammed by :

```
nautilus[49268]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55b1f806e230
```

I'm desperately trying to know which extension it is and/or how to solve it but I can't manage to get some log from nautilus.
I have also tried to remove all extension and plugin from nautilus without success.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What extensions have you installed? We can not know what you have done.

Comment: Include the output of `dpkg -l | grep nautilus` in your question: use "edit" to add it.